# Accessing a JSON variable pre-fixed with a @

Tags: json, attributes, prefix

How do you access JSON that has elements prefixed with a @?  For example;

{@Lx: "100", @ItemId: "92005", @LineNumber: "100", QuantityLx: {…}, WeightLx: {…}, …}

I get this error if I user the @ in javascript, and the element is undefined is I omit it;

VM1825:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Just need to encapsulate the field in brackets, for example obj["@Lx"].